# Choosing the smallest EGLConfig for offscreen rendering

Tags: opengl, 3d, egl

I'm developing an application which runs on different EGL implementations and platfroms, incl. Windows (ANGLE), Linux (Mesa, NVidia). The application spends most of the time doing offscreen rendering in many threads, hence many EGLContexts with FBOs in them.

Is it necessary to choose EGLConfig with required color buffer size for an off-screen context and pbuffer, if I'm only rendering to FBO? Or is it sufficient to choose the smallest EGLConfig available?

Example: the system provides EGLConfigs with RGB565 and no depth/stencil (16-bit), RGB888 (24-bit), RGBA8888 (32-bit). I'm creating a EGLContext with RGB565 config, then I'm creating FBO and attaching an RGBA texture to it together with depth and stencil renderbuffers.

Comment: Empty list (or maybe only `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE` if you want to use `EGL_OPENGL_API`) + [`EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context.txt) & [`GL_OES_surfaceless_context`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_surfaceless_context.txt)?

Comment: How to choose the smallest `EGLConfig` is perfectly clear. But does it put restrictions on FBO attachment formats? This is the question I should've asked in the first place, actually, I just couldn't word it...